# I have white space in my table

Tags: html, css, image, html-table, whitespace

I have white space in my table. I've searched the forum but it seem I have everything setup correct. Has it something to do with the images?
Cellpadding is here but no luck.

Does anyone know where it goes wrong? I've tried block to but with no luck, I know I must be missing something but I can't seem to find it.
I can't add any more details to this post.

[image: example]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <title>House of Talents</title>
<style type="text/css">

img     {display: inline-block}

.floatRight {float:right;}
.floatLeft      {float:none;}

.mobileShow {display: none}

.MPED_ULSortable {margin: 0 !important;padding: 0 !important;}

.cornerAll {border-radius: 0px;}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 850px), (max-width: 850px) {
        .logo {width: 180px;height: auto;}
        .marginBottom {
                margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
        .contentTable {
                width:100% !important;
                float: none !important;
        }
        td[class="floatLeft"] {
                float:left !important;
                width: 100% !important;
        }
        td[class="floatRight"] {
                width: 100% !important;
                float:right !important;
        }
        .mobileHide {display:none}
        .mobileShow {display: block !important}
        
        .resizeImage img {
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
        }
}
</style>
  </head>

  

    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="MPED_CONTENT">
            <div class="MPED_CONTENTBLOCK">
              <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td style="width: 850px; max-width: 850px;">
                              <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td class="resizeImage" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #243e55; font-weight: bold; background-color: #f3716d; width: 425px; padding-left: 60px;" width="425"><br>
                                    <br>
                                     <img src="http://images.m9.mailplus.nl/user3900328/765/arcq_wit_4x.png" border="0" width="150" height="37" mpdatacustomsize="true"><br>
                                    <br>
                                     <span style="color: #e94b5a; font-family: helvetica;">&nbsp;<br>
                                    </span></td>

                                    <td class="resizeImage" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #243e55; font-weight: bold; background-color: #f3716d; width: 425px;" width="425">&nbsp;</td>
                                  </tr>

                                  <tr>
                                    <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #43565e;">
                                      <blockquote>
                                        <p class="p1">&nbsp;</p>
                                      </blockquote>
                                    </td>

                                    <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #43565e;">
                                      <p class="p1"><span style="font-family: helvetica;"><img src="http://images.m9.mailplus.nl/user3900328/131/welcome0.png" border="0" width="425" height="425" mpdatacustomsize="true" ><br>
                                      </span></p>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>

                                  <tr>
                                    <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #43565e; line-height: 18px; background-color: #e7f0f7;">&nbsp;</td>

                                    <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #43565e; line-height: 18px; background-color: #e7f0f7;">&nbsp;</td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Step 1: Don't use tables for layout. uses tables for tabular data and CSS for layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<p>` tags are adding margins by default. There is no css class `p1` defined, but setting margins to zero on that class will fix this.

**Note**

I am purposely *not* addressing the bad practice involved with using tables for layout (or the other myriad other bad practices in this code).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <title>House of Talents</title>
<style type="text/css">

img     {display: inline-block}

.floatRight {float:right;}
.floatLeft      {float:none;}

.mobileShow {display: none}

.MPED_ULSortable {margin: 0 !important;padding: 0 !important;}

.cornerAll {border-radius: 0px;}

.p1 { margin: 0 };

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 850px), (max-width: 850px) {
        .logo {width: 180px;height: auto;}
        .marginBottom {
                margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
        .contentTable {
                width:100% !important;
                float: none !important;
        }
        td[class="floatLeft"] {
                float:left !important;
                width: 100% !important;
        }
        td[class="floatRight"] {
                width: 100% !important;
                float:right !important;
        }
        .mobileHide {display:none}
        .mobileShow {display: block !important}
        
        .resizeImage img {
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
        }
}
</style>
  </head>

  

    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="MPED_CONTENT">
            <div class="MPED_CONTENTBLOCK">
              <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td style="width: 850px; max-width: 850px;">
                              <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td class="resizeImage" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #243e55; font-weight: bold; background-color: #f3716d; width: 425px; padding-left: 60px;" width="425"><br>
                                    <br>
                                     <img src="http://images.m9.mailplus.nl/user3900328/765/arcq_wit_4x.png" border="0" width="150" height="37" mpdatacustomsize="true"><br>
                                    <br>
                                     <span style="color: #e94b5a; font-family: helvetica;">&nbsp;<br>
                                    </span></td>

                                    <td class="resizeImage" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #243e55; font-weight: bold; background-color: #f3716d; width: 425px;" width="425">&nbsp;</td>
                                  </tr>

                                  <tr>
                                    <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #43565e;">
                                      <blockquote>
                                        <p class="p1">&nbsp;</p>
                                      </blockquote>
                                    </td>

                                    <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #43565e;">
                                      <p class="p1"><span style="font-family: helvetica;"><img src="http://images.m9.mailplus.nl/user3900328/131/welcome0.png" border="0" width="425" height="425" mpdatacustomsize="true" ><br>
                                      </span></p>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>

                                  <tr>
                                    <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #43565e; line-height: 18px; background-color: #e7f0f7;">&nbsp;</td>

                                    <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #43565e; line-height: 18px; background-color: #e7f0f7;">&nbsp;</td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello

Thanks this helped!
I'm aware that this is a bad method and I learned it a different way. But this mailing program seems to use this old dated method.

Comment: You are welcome. I assumed it was for e-mail purposes. I get that. Please accept my answer if this solved your problem. Thanks!